# Android Material TextInputLayout slow inflation

Tags: android

I have a recycler view that has a list of rows that contain a couple of inputs. I have noticed it has been slow on initial loading so figured something on the inflation side is causing this. I  confirmed this by doing a simple timer before and after inflation and saw that on average it is taking about 30 ms just to inflate the views. The binding of the views is fine and is at about 5ms on average.

I'm omitting the entire layout of the row for brevity, but the inputs are setup as follows:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/details_input_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:hint="@string/details"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/go_btn"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/title">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/details_input"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginVertical="8dp"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:maxLines="3"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            app:autoSizeTextType="uniform" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

The style for my inputlayouts is as follows:

```
<style name="TextInputLayoutStyle" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">
    <item name="expandedHintEnabled">false</item>

    <item name="boxStrokeColor">@color/box_color</item>
    <item name="hintTextColor">@color/box_focused_color</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/box_unfocused_color</item>
</style>
```

The root layout of the row is a constraint layout with no other nesting. If I get rid of the textinputlayout then the time to inflate goes down drastically (down to approx 8ms) and I no longer notice any sort of lag on initial loading. Even if I just add 1 of the 4 inputlayouts back, the slowness comes back.

Is there something I can do to fix this lag? Perhaps some xml attribute? I need the inputlayout for the styling and the ability to easily show error messages and hints that I think are lacking without the inputlayout.

I see that there [was a commit](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/commit/26d862bc5433eb50ba0875e136ff937d4e5ae617) to address inflation issues but that was released in `'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.0'` which is what my project is using.